# Magento 2.4.x, How to assign company to customer

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2-b2b, company

In Magento 2.4.x, How to assign the company to customers???
I am using B2B, the M2EE version.
I tried [this](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/assign-customer-to-company-magento-2-b2b/) solution but it is not working.

Here is my sample code, I tried.

```
<?php
class YourClass {
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Company\Api\CompanyManagementInterface $companyRepository
) {
    $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
}

public function assignedCompany()
{
    $companyId = 10;
    $customerId = 1;
    $company = null;
    if($companyId && $customerId) {
        $company = $this->companyRepository->assignCustomer($companyId,$customerId);
    }
    return $company;
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah same it doesn't work for me. Did you manage how to assign programmatically?  @Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old, but I just toughed through this myself in **Magento 2.4.3**, and I hope this code helps someone out. I found that you must add the customer to the **company structure** using the structure manager. The code will look something like this:

```
<?PHP

use Magento\Company\Api\Data\StructureInterface;
use Magento\Company\Api\CompanyManagementInterface;
use Magento\Company\Model\Company\Structure;

class YourClass {
public function __construct(
    CompanyManagementInterface $companyRepository
    Structure $structureManager
) {
    $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
    $this->structureManager  = $structureManager;
}

public function assignToCompany()
{
    $companyId = 10;
    $customerId = 1;
    $company = null;

    if($companyId && $customerId) {
        $company = $this->companyRepository->assignCustomer($companyId,$customerId);

        $adminId = $this->companyRepository->getAdminByCompanyId($companyId)->getId();
        $structId = $this->structureManager->getStructureByCustomerId($adminId)->getId();

        $structureManager->addNode(
          $customerId,
          StructureInterface::TYPE_CUSTOMER,
          $structId
        );
    }
    return $company;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Magento itself does this (The simplest way without team or structure):

First you should add your `customer_id` as `super_user_id` in Company object. So,

```
$company = $this->companyRepository->getById($companyId);
$company->setSuperUserId($customer->getId);
$this->companyRepository->save($company);
```

Then you should also update customer's extension_attributes. So,

```
// Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper dataObjectHelper
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
        $customer,
        [
            'extension_attributes' => [
                'company_attributes' => [
                    'company_id' => $companyId,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'job_title' => 'Sales Rep'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        CustomerInterface::class
    );

$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

Answer (score -1):

If allowed in the configuration, the company administrator adds users to the company. However, the company assignment of a customer profile can also be made or changed from the Admin.
Assign a customer to a company

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Customers > All Customers.
2. Find the customer in the grid and click Edit in the Action column.
3. In the left panel, choose Account Information.
4. Click Associate to Company and type the first few letters of the company name in the input box.